# Geometry of SAR Imaging, how to calculate the bottom side length of a triangle given two sides and the median angle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am interested in calculating the bottom side length of a triangle. I have included a graphic.

We have an obtuse triangle with two side lengths $R_n$ and $R_f$, we also have the angle between the median line and the bottom side length $\psi$.

Given this information, the bottom side length is

$$W_g = \frac{R_f-R_n}{cos\  \psi}$$

But I am rusty on my trigonometry and geometry. Can anyone help me prove this relationship?

Thank you!

[image: SAR Imaging]

Comment: That is an approximate relation, valid for $R_n,R_f >\!\!> W_g$.

Comment: Using cosine rule for triangles formed by median and $\frac{W_g}2$ parts: $W_g^2+4l^2+4W_g l\cos\psi=4R_f^2$, $W_g^2+4l^2-4W_g l \cos\psi=4R_n^2$. Solving for $W_g$ gives more precise relation.